# Smooth animation for the custom cursor when hovered over an element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make the transition of the cursor as smooth as possible, right now the size changes abruptly when hovered over the desired element. Any idea on how I can make it smooth, like the size increases smoothly, just a better animation compared to what is happening right now. Here is the current code. I've also attached the gif of what is happening right now. https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1v2Z.gif

```
<style>
.cursor {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    background: #ffffff;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    user-select: none;
    pointer-events: none;
    /*            mix-blend-mode: color;*/
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.9);
    z-index: 9999;
    transition:"";
    /*    mix-blend-mode: difference;*/

}
</style>

 <div class="cursor"><span id="myspan"></span></div>

    <script>
        var cursor = document.querySelector('.cursor');
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
            cursor.style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
            cursor.style.top = e.pageY + 'px';
        });

    </script>


 <div class="div-33">
        <a href="" class="a1" style="cursor:none">
            <span class="span-11 cursorHover div-34">
                LET’S GET SOMETHIN’
                <br />
                COOKIN’.
                <img src="imgs/im/Vector.png" class="arrow mt-4" />
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>

    <script>
        var cursor3 = document.querySelector('.cursorHover');
        span = document.getElementById("myspan");
        txt = document.createTextNode("Say hi!");

        cursor3.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
            var element = document.querySelector('.cursor');
            element.style.transform = 'scale(6)';
            //            element.style.transition = 'width 2s linear 1s';

            element.style.background = '#FF6E1D';
            span.appendChild(txt);



        });

        cursor3.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
            var element = document.querySelector('.cursor');
            element.style.transform = '';
            element.style.background = '';
            span.removeChild(txt);
        })

    </script>
```

Comment: Please make the code into a snippet - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example At the moment it gives errors as element .cursor does not exist.

Comment: Oh sorry forgot to add my original cursor code. I've added now.

Comment: run your code, looks smooth. to say what's wrong a full page is needed

Comment: @Isha you added your email in the code.Remove that if you added by mistake:))

Comment: yeh removed, it thanks for letting me know!! @Jai248

Comment: Have you tried tranition on transform (not on width)?

Comment: The question's [version history still has the email address in older revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77866310/timeline#history_5f82fd9e-9f9b-40f6-8f08-ccd01beca448). Maybe you want to delete the question and ask it again..?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `transition:all ease-in-out 0.25s;`, which will animate `all` properties over a period of `0.25s`, with the `ease-in-out` speed curve transition. You can read more available options here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions.

I also changed your cursors position to fixed, so that it doesn't affect the width and height of the page which could add vertical/horizontal scrollbars (depending on where this behaviour is on the page).

```js
var cursor = document.querySelector('.cursor');
document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  cursor.style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
  cursor.style.top = e.pageY + 'px';
});

var cursor3 = document.querySelector('.div-33');
span = document.getElementById("myspan");
txt = document.createTextNode("Say hi!");

cursor3.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
  var element = document.querySelector('.cursor');
  element.style.transform = 'scale(6)';
  //            element.style.transition = 'width 2s linear 1s';

  element.style.background = '#FF6E1D';
  span.appendChild(txt);
});

cursor3.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  var element = document.querySelector('.cursor');
  element.style.transform = '';
  element.style.background = '';
  span.removeChild(txt);
})
```

```css
.cursor {
    content: " ";
    position: fixed;
    background: #ffffff;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    user-select: none;
    pointer-events: none;
    /*            mix-blend-mode: color;*/
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.9);
    z-index: 9999;
    transition:all ease-in-out 0.25s;
    transform-origin: top left;
    /*    mix-blend-mode: difference;*/

}
```

```html
<div class="cursor"><span id="myspan"></span></div>

 <div class="div-33">
        <a href="" class="a1" style="cursor:none">
            <span class="span-11 cursorHover div-34">
                LET’S GET SOMETHIN’
                <br />
                COOKIN’.
                <img src="imgs/im/Vector.png" class="arrow mt-4" />
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
```